# Transposh плагин WP. Исчезают флажки языков при загрузке страниц в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, веб-программирование

Столкнулся с проблемой отображения языковых флажков в шапке сайте темы Aurum версии 2.9.7 CMS WordPress. В оригинальной версии сайта всё нормально отображается, а вот при загрузке страницы на мобильном флажки сначала мелькают и после окончания загрузки исчезают. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем может быть вызвана эта проблема?
Вот нижеследующий код, который я добавил в header.php темы, для отображения флажков в шапке сайта:

```
<div id="headwidget" align="right">
    <?php if(function_exists("transposh_widget")) { transposh_widget(array(), array('title' => '', 'widget_file' => 'flags/tpw_flags.php')); }?>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на сайт с проблемой](http://cosmowebtest.info/?lang=ru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в файл стилей

```
#headwidget {
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, все работает супер!.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Я тут ещё новенький, только учусь. Спасибо буду внимателен.

Comment: После добавления в файл стилей z-index: 1001; всё хорошо работает, но при переключении на другой язык флажки опять пропадают, в опции темы в Custom CSS есть вкладки : General Style, Less, Sass. Я добавил стили в General. Нужно ли ещё что нибудь добавить в стили или это проблема решаема через php?